# Использование pcap для получения пакетов отправленных на другой компьютер

Tags: pcap, libpcap

Каким образом используя библиотеку winpcap возможно получить пакеты, адресованные в сети на другой компьютер используя компьютер в этой же сети? Компьютеры подключены через роутер или через свитч.

Comment: Если не прибегать к технике переполнения mac-таблиц свитча, то никак. А таблицы переполнять не стоит, свитч вместо того что бы открыться может например зависнуть. Вот если бы у вас был управляемый свитч, с возможностью зеркалирования портов, то тогда легко, просто на свитче указать свой порт зеркалом того, который собираетесь слушать

Comment: А как определить есть ли такая функция у свитча?

Comment: зайти в настройки и поискать. Так же поможет документация на свитч. Ну еще можно на цену посмотреть, если стоит менее 5000 руб то скорее всего нет